# TYPO3 change the site url to Localhost after copying from live site

Tags: typo3, typo3-6.2.x

I am new in TYPO3, I copied a TYPO3 system to localhost so I can develop offline, no my problem is all the link points to the live site. my_live_cite.com
What should I change in the backend to redirect all links and ref to localhost ?

Answer (score 2):

Check and adapt for sys_domain records (see root page PID=0).

See also TypoScript (TYPO3 backend modul `Templates`) and check/adapt the domain you are looking for to change. Select in TypoScript Template module *TypoScript object browser* where you can search in constants and setup (configuration) for strings.
Cause of TypoScript can bee different ways, to handle domains. Have a look at `config.baseURL` and maybe `page.config.baseURL`

Comment: Do not forget `config.absRefPrefix`.

Comment: The website uses Fluxtemplate so I see no Typoscript template !! config.absRefPrefix is set to / , config.domain is set to localhost:8000

Comment: I just managed by changing in the DB all the value in sys_template table, I know it is not perfect but it worked